# View path inside default.php in joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, components

I'm building a component view in Joomla and I'm using a lot of JS in the file inside the component myview/tmpl/default.php.

Where is the best folder to store a separate JS file in a component and how to get a link to that file inside the default.php

Answer (score 1):

The recommended location for any web accessible media (images, javascript, css etc) required by a Joomla! Extension (component, module etc) is the `/media` directory. This is covered in the [Manifest documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) on the [Joomla! docs website.](http://docs.joomla.org/)

To put it simply, in your extensions directory include a directory called `media` (or something meaningful to you). In that store all of your web accessible content, you can even have sub-directories like `images` or `js` or `css` or all of them.

Then in your manifest XML add the `media` element, like:

```xml
    <media folder="media" destination="com_example">
            <filename>logo.png</filename>
            <folder>css</folder>
            <folder>js</folder>
    </media>
```

The Joomla installer will then create a folder for you inside `/media` called `com_example`, then you can access all your media files with calls like:

```php
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . 'media/com_example/css/example.css');
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . 'media/com_example/css/example.js');
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root() . 'media/com_example/'; ?>logo.png"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cppl  but I ran into a new problem. generating the site in a multi-language environment I'm using JText inside the JS so I can't use a .js file. I'm stacked again with too long files with JS and PHP. any solution for that ?

Comment: Yes - see this answer on using JText in Javascript.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122021/add-language-constants-to-joomla-component-javascript/16136981#16136981

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php echo JURI::root();?>components/com_mycomponent
```

Comment: This is surly a good solution but I think cppl described the correct answer for the problem.. thanks @Praveen kalal

Answer (score 0):

This will give you path to components/CURRENT COMPONENT.

```
echo JPATH_COMPONENT;
```

[Source](https://docs.joomla.org/Constants)