# Hiding the word "joomla" from a script in contact form

Tags: joomla3.0

Whenever i create a contact form in my Joomla! 3.3.6, some script appears in the the page's HTML code that contains many words ***Joomla*** in it. I'd like to change those ***Joomla*** words and replace them with another words (i.e. Foo) for some security issue. I'd like to know whether or not i'm able to do so and how.

That script is:

```
<script>(function(){var strings={"JLIB_FORM_FIELD_INVALID":"\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u062f \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0639\u062a\u0628\u0631:&#160"};if(typeof Joomla=='undefined'){Joomla={};Joomla.JText=strings;}
else{Joomla.JText.load(strings);}})();</script>
```

I have no idea whether a plugin or an extension creates it or not.

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script seems to be translating some text required for the form to use in its javascript, eg validation messages. It does this using a javascript version of JText, which is part of core Joomla.  There is some info on how that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122021/add-language-constants-to-joomla-component-javascript).  Weirdly, there seems to be little information in the official Joomla documentation about it.

The main JText function it is calling appears here: media/system/js/core.js

I'm sure it would be possible to write a plug-in to remove this script before the page is rendered and then to translate any untranslated text with your own scripts.  However, I'm not sure I see any security benefit in doing this so it seems a waste of time.

Ultimately, someone sniffing a site for what it is built in is far more likely to see if core files exist by going direct to places like media/system/js/core.js, rather than to scan the code for the word "Joomla" - which would trigger a lot of false-positives (any site which just mentions Joomla) and negatives (any page which doesn't have a form on it).  It also does not reveal the version of Joomla, which is the info a hacker would more likely be after.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to search for the script (i.e via Notepad++) in the whole directory. It must be a plugin for the contact form that has some inline script in it.
also do you use any special third party plugin or so? that might be the source of it.

PS: also i had some similar experience, i don't know exactly how i got rid of those words, but like you, i wanted to do that to hide the fact that i'm using joomla for security.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually Joomla who add this, from the file: Joomlainstall/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

And load it globaly from:

Joomlainstall/libraries/cms/html/formbehavior.php

The developer ad that code by using the function, JText, for an example:

JText::_( 'COM_CONTACT_EMAIL_FORM' )

In my case it was the plugin ContactUs Form who add the javascript. If  JText is not used, it is not loaded. If I disabled the   plugin, the javascript was then not loaded. If you have that plugin enabled, my be try an other contact form?

For security reson it is bad programming by the developer off Joomla, for sure.